# Resize div along with content inside according to window size

Tags: html, css, formatting, resize, containers

I have looked up a million techniques and I can't get this to work and I know there is other posts similar to this.  I'm sorry if it bugs anyone but I need specific instructions for my code cuz me stupid. Thank you so much in advance! I want the div container contentContactBox, along with all of the divs inside it, to proportionally resize when the browser window is resized. On the left side of the contentcontactBox is some text and on the right is a google map imbed.  I want them all to shrink proportionally with the size of the window.

Note: I know I probably need to take out position: absolute out of the children divs

HTML:

```
<div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade in">
    <div id="contentBoxContact">
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div id="contact-content">
        <h1>Come see us downtown<br> and have a beer!</h1><br>
        <h2 style="text-decoration: underline">Phone Number:</h2>
        <h2>555-555-5555</h2><br>
        <h2 style="text-decoration: underline">Email:</h2>
        <h2>fakeemail@gmail.com</h2><br>
        <h2 style="text-decoration: underline">Address:</h2>
        <h2>
          Fake Place<br>
          414 2nd Avenue<br>
          Fake Location<br>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding-top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: url(/images/TaphouseTaps2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


.tab-content{
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#contentBoxContact {
  margin-top: 54px;
  width: 1185px;
  height: 560px;
  margin-left: -593px;
  background: rgba(34,34,34,.75);
}

#contact-content {
  position: absolute
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  line-height: 2px;
  font-family: Titillium Web, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: white; 
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 550px;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using bootstrap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the vw value to make divs that shrink proportionally with the window.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gokcLvtv/11/)

HTML

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

CSS

```
.one {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background-color: #76ccde;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.two {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background-color: #c976de;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.three {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  background-color: #a7de76;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! You are my hero! I can't believe I couldn't find that anywhere. Anytime i searched for it people were using these really overly complicated techniques and I knew there had to be an easier way.

Comment: Is there a way to make the child divs shrink at the same speed so that they stay as one unit?

Comment: To use your example, if you were to place the smaller ones inside the bigger ones, they shrink proportionally with the window size but not each other so as the window size shrinks they become out of place.

Answer (score -1):

i think u need to use px instead of % in child div and for parent use

```css
height: auto;
width:auto;
```

Comment: I am using px for the child divs... I will try auto for parent but I don't think its that simple.

Comment: Also if I use auto as the height and width then how do i set the width and height of the div. Its a box holding the content so i want it to be a certain size.

Comment: min-height: 400 px;
min-width:400px;

Comment: if u have set the width and height of child then u no need to set any thing for parent just use auto

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you take a look into Bootstrap. It's known for being dynamic; if the screen size changes, the whole CSS for that page changes. Here's a link: [Bootstrap 3](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/). Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am using bootstrap.