# Absolute position div goes out of window when opening console

Tags: html, css

There's a div under a div or wrapper. The sub div is absolute positioned to align it horizontally and vertically. But the problem is when I open console and resize it i.e. move upwards div goes out of the window. Please i want to fix this. Please help me fix this. I want div to stay in it's position (not position: fixed).

[image]

Code:

```css
div.content{
  background-color: #F44336;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "content" style = "font-size: 48px;">
    Hi This is cool man! This is amazing.<br />
    Hi This is cool man! This is amazing.<br />
    Hi This is cool man! This is amazing.<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please Help! And ya, please tell me if it is possible via pure javascript. I don't like jQuery answers. Thank you!

Comment: There is nothing to fix as it is behaving correctly. What is your concern about this? That someone will look at your website with a height of 100px? Your div will disappear when the window height is smaller than your content height, it will do this regardless of the console window, you can do the same thing if you just resized your browser

Comment: You can make content of div to [auto-resize according to window size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36121945/380331)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

Those are relative units. Either change them to absolute or let the parent have a static size.

Comment: The css are there to vertically and horizontally center the div

Comment: I know, so what is the problem? _Either change them to absolute or let the parent have a static size._ That just means that the second option is probably the better one for him

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a maximum height relative to the viewport height. By applying `max-height: 90vh` (and possibly `overflow-y:auto`) the container itself will never be taller than 90% of the viewport height.

```css
div.content{
  background-color: #F44336;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  max-height: 90vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "content" style = "font-size: 48px;">
    Hi This is cool man! This is amazing.<br />
    Hi This is cool man! This is amazing.<br />
    Hi This is cool man! This is amazing.<br />
  </div>
</div>
```